# Dynamic routes not working when app is exported to static files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a site that is statically exported, and has dynamic routes.

This site works fine in dev mode. However if I build & export it, and then [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) the static files, it has an issue.

**You can go to the site root and click on a link, which will take you to a dynamic post page like `http://localhost:3000/post/1` and will work, but if you refresh the page (or visit directly) it 404s.**

[image]

**Why is this? Do dynamic routes, that need to access the router query object, not work when statically exported?**

[The dynamic route docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) don't mention any caveats to dynamic routes when used with static export.

### The code:

Taking the [next.js static example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-static-export) to start with, I edited it’s `pages/post/[id].tsx` by removing the `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` (as I don’t require build time static generation) and added clientside fetching on mount. I’m grabbing the [router.query.id](http://router.query.id/) value and using it to fetch data:

⚡ [Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wilson-t8rvlh?file=/pages/post/%5Bid%5D.tsx) (which works fine as its running in dev, not exported served files)

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { GetPost } from '../../lib/postdata_api'
import { PostData } from '../../types/postdata'

const Post = () => {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState<null | PostData>(null)
  const router = useRouter()
  const id = router.query.id as string
  const fetchData = async () => setPostData(await GetPost(id))

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) return
    fetchData()
  }, [router, router.isReady])

  if (!postData) return 'Loading...'

  return (
    <main>
      <Head>
        <title>{postData.title}</title>
      </Head>

      <h1>{postData.title}</h1>

      <p>{postData.body}</p>

      <Link href="/">
        <a>Go back to home</a>
      </Link>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Post
```

#### Expected Behavior

I expected it to behave the as it does it dev. Meaning a user can:

- click a link on the root page
- view the dynamic post page eg `/post/1`
- refresh / directly visit this post (without it 404ing)

#### To Reproduce

- Download the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wilson-t8rvlh?file=/pages/post/%5Bid%5D.tsx) or [github repo](https://github.com/AshConnolly/nextjs-dynamic-route-export-issue)
- run `npm run export && serve out`
- visit `http://localhost:3000`
- click a link to a post
- press refresh to see the 404

Comment: Could you plz try accessing the page with a trailing slash?

Comment: @IrfanullahJan Good idea! but sadly that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Add the following configuration to `next.config.js` and then make the export again:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

### Explanation

It's possible to fix this behavior changing manually all routes produced by the export process to folders and renaming each `*.html` file to `index.html`, as follows:

Produced route by `next export`:

```
/posts/1.html
```

"Fixed" route:

```
/posts/1/index.html
```

So, if the page is refreshed when the browser has `/posts/1` as url, the route will acquire a trailing slash and will become `/posts/1/`, the HTTP petition will be done correctly because the HTTP server picks up the file `index.html` under any directory by default, and the static page will be shown.

Apparently, this behavior was the default prior `Next.js v9` when export, and can be enabled again adding the following configuration to the file `next.config.js` (in order to avoid doing the change per route manually):

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

I know it's a little late, but I found out this solution when I faced the same problem yesterday.

Source: [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use 'serve' from Vercel. To have pretty URLs, you need to config rewrite for the server.

According to this instruction https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#rewrites-array. You need to add this config to make it work with pretty URLs.

```
// public/serve.json
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/post/*", "destination": "/post/[id].html" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Why would I need to do this when it works as expected in dev mode? Not sure why I'd need to specify a rewrite when I'm not trying to "map an incoming request path to a different destination path". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because you choose to export and serve as static files. you lose some features, such as rewrite urls. Please read the section 'Unsupported features in Next.js static HTML export' in https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-static-html-export-next-js/. So you need to configure 'serve' (your webserver) to (re)implement the rewrite urls feature.

Comment: You can use next start to use next webserver, it (maybe) run the same as dev mode, but without hot loading, etc... https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli

Comment: That didn't work. It makes the page read router query object as { query: {
id: "[id].html"}}, which breaks any client side data fetching as it tries to get "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/[id].html"